# Finding Sequence of numbers in Text file

Tags: vb.net

Hello I'm having quite some trouble with this task that was given to me.
I need to find a Sequence of 8 consecutive numbers in a Text file and Put that Line into a MsgBox.
So far I've only found

```
For Each i As Char In fileLocation
            If IsNumeric(i) Then
                result += i
            End If
        Next`
MsgBox(result)
```

But that won't help me I guess

Edit:
an example Line woudl look like this:

```
 ! MK 90 GRAD ALU L  10793013  144  63.00                90       1     3745  !
```

In this case I would need the 10793013 as an output

Edit 2:
this is the code I currently managed to create

```
Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fileLocation) 
    Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1 
        concounter = 0
        zeileInhalt = objReader.ReadLine() 
        ListBox1.Items.Add(zeileInhalt)          
        For Each zeichen As Char In zeileInhalt 
            If IsNumeric(zeichen) Then
                concounter += 1
                vorhanden = True
                If vorhanden = False Then
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(zeileInhalt)
                End If
            ElseIf IsNumeric(zeichen) = False And concounter = 8 Then
                concounter = 0
            ElseIf IsNumeric(zeichen) = False And concounter < 8 Then
                concounter = 0
                ListBox1.Items.Remove(zeileInhalt)
            ElseIf concounter > 8 Then
                concounter = 0
                ListBox1.Items.Remove(zeileInhalt)
                vorhanden = False
            End If
        Next
    Loop
    'For i As Integer = 0 To fileLocation.Length <> -1   
    objReader.Close()
```

The counter itself appears to work however for some reason no entries end up in my listbox.
am I missing a case where the entries are getting removed?
PS: I hope you don't mind the german variable names. If you do

```
zeileInhalt = content of the row
zeichen = character
vorhanden = existing
```

Comment: so what exactly is missing? probably you need a counter to check the consecutivity, right?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander thats exactly what I need

Comment: then try to introduce it in your if clause and reset it to zero once it's not numeric!

Comment: I only see 3 possibilities of "a Sequence of 8 consecutive numbers". 01234567, 12345678, 23456789  Is this what you are looking for? Or are you looking for any 8 digits in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach to try out:

```
Dim values() As String
Using objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fileLocation)
    Do While Not objReader.EndOfStream
        values = objReader.ReadLine().Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        For Each value As String In values
            value = value.Trim()
            If value.Length = 8 AndAlso value.All(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c)) Then
                ListBox1.Items.Add(value)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Loop
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

try to introduce a counter to check the consecutivity in your if clause and reset it and result string to zero once it's not numeric!

```
Dim result As String = ""
Dim conCounter As Integer = 0
For Each i As Char In fileLocation
    If Char.IsDigit(i) Then
        conCounter = (conCounter + 1)
        result = (result + i)
    Else
        conCounter = 0
        If (result.Length < 8) Then
            result = ""
        End If
        
    End If
    
Next
MsgBox(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for each word in fileLocation
Dim noExp As New Regex("([0-9]{8,11})")
Dim m As Match = noExp.Match(word)
If Not m.Success Then Throw New Exception("No sequence number found")
Dim c = m.Groups(1).Captures(0)
Msgbox(c.value)
next
```

how about this ?